# Change children state from parent component in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I've red some articles about my question and i understand thatif i want to change the state of child component from Parent component i have to lift the state in the parent component, but i don't want to do this.

I have 2 components:

```js
const Parent = () => {
  const changeChild = () => {
  
  }
  
  return (
    <button onClick={changeChild}>change state</button>
    <Children/>
  )
}


const Children = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(false); //this state should be changed by parent to TRUE
}
```

Question: How to change the state to `true` what is located in child component using `changeChild` from parent? Who can help?

Comment: Why don't you want to lift the state to the parent? IMO, you are making your job harder by looking for alternatives.

Comment: @TylerZeller, coyuld you please help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66381227/change-the-state-according-to-event-in-reactjs/66381338#66381338

Answer (score 3):

You can try an alternative way. Check this snippet using useRef, forwardRef and useImperativeHandle.

**Parent.js**

```
import { useRef } from "react";
import { Child } from "./Child";

export default function () {
  const ref = useRef();

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => ref.current.setState()}>
        Click me to toggle the value in child
      </button>
      <Child ref={ref} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Child.js**

```
 import { forwardRef, useState, useImperativeHandle } from "react";

 export const Child = forwardRef(function (props, ref) {
  //this state should be changed by parent to TRUE
  const [state, setState] = useState(false);

  function changeValue() {
    return function () {
      setState(!state);
    };
  }
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    setState: () => changeValue()()
  }));

  return (
    <div>
      <b>changed value from parent</b> :{" "}
      {state ? "Parent triggered to true" : "Parent triggered to false"}
    </div>
  );
});
```

**Note**: This is not the recommended, try to use lift the state. This is for just understanding purpose and this is an anti-pattern

Working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/updating-child-state-from-parent-without-lifting-state-dnt-m3rmk)

Comment: ,could you help with this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66381227/change-the-state-according-to-event-in-reactjs/66381338#66381338

Comment: Sure, if it helped you kindly accept and vote so it will be helpful for future references

Comment: related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66381227/change-the-state-according-to-event-in-reactjs/66381338#66381338 , what changes should i add? Sorry if i bother you. Thanks, it will help a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Put the state into the parent instead, and pass it down:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [childState, setChildState] = useState(false);
  const changeChild = () => setChildState(!childState);
  
  return (
    <button onClick={changeChild}>change state</button>
    <Children state={childState} />
  )
}


const Children = ({ state }) => {

}
```

Comment: They mentioned they didn't want to hoist the state, but I agree that this is the most preferable/simplest solution, if possible.

Comment: @CertainPerformance ,could you help with this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66381227/change-the-state-according-to-event-in-reactjs/66381338#66381338